# Firebase security rules set a document not allowed on update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I currently use the `set` method in firestore, to set and update a document.

I have a set method implemented to both create or update a given document. I am able to create the document just fine, but when I go to update it (when there is already a document that exists), it gives me a permissions error, but I have tested and allowed create and update `if true`, is there any other write rule that I need to add?

```
await db.collection('theCollection').doc(doc.id).collection('nextCollection').doc("" + currentDate).set({
                        status: status,
                        active: true
                    }, {merge: true});
```

```
match /collectionOne/{docOne}/collectionTwo/{docTwo} {
        allow write:  if false;
        allow create: if true; //these are only for testing purposes, it is not usually just true.
        allow update: if true;
        allow read:   if true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your write rule is overriding the update rule, write rule is generalised rule for these three operations **create**,**update**,**delete** so update your database rules as following

```
match /collectionOne/{docOne}/collectionTwo/{docTwo} {
        allow delete:  if false;//if you want to disable deleting
        allow create: if true; //these are only for testing purposes, it is not usually just true.
        allow update: if true;
        allow read:   if true;
    }
```

Comment: I see, what I don't understand is why the create works, just not update?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation about [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) which explains how to break down `read` and `write` into more granular operations.

Actually "a `write` rule can be broken into `create`, `update`, and `delete`"

In your Security Rule code you mix `write`, `create` and `update`.

You should do something as follows:

```
match /collectionOne/{docOne}/collectionTwo/{docTwo} {
        allow create: if true; //these are only for testing purposes, it is not usually just true.
        allow update: if true;
        allow delete: if ....;
        allow read:   if true;
    }
```

Comment: I see, what I don't understand is why the create works, just not update?